# Get form parameter value from request in Play 2.0 Scala controller

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In Play 2.0 Scala application I have simple page with Form with one parameter. It redirects to another page, where I want to do something with parameter from the form. How can I get it?

I'm looking for something like

```
request.formData.get("paramName")
```

I know `request.body`, but still don't know how to get single parameter value from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say that the easyest way to retrieve forms data is to use the `Form` structure in `play.api.data`. So here is how you could do it in **play2.0-rc1**

```
val form = Form[(String, String)](
  tuple(
    "paramName1" -> nonEmptyText,
    "paramName2" -> nonEmptyText
  )
)

form.bindFromRequest.fold(
  failure => (),//do smthg with the failure info
  { case (p1, p2) => println(p1);println(p1)}
)
```

Instead of using `nonEmptyText` you might use `of[String]`.

Check what is put in your hands for that mapping here [Forms Helper](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Forms.scala).
Some other information that should help you further are [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaForms).

Answer (score 8):

If a post request with following may work

request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("myparam")[0];

Comment: In scala this is: `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("myparam")`

Comment: This is so bad but its the answer